# Regex that selects line break after certain number of characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex string that selects each line break that follows a certain number of characters (in my case 19).

This would select the whole line--but I would only want the line break selected that fulfills this condition:

```
.{19,}[^\n]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated (I obviously don't really know my way around regexs.)

Essentially what I'm trying to do is a search&replace with a text-editor that supports regex to get rid off line-breaks from an OCRd book. My somewhat heuristic approach is that every line shorter than 19 characters is likely a paragraph break (It's a very small book) and should keep the line break while all other lines should have the break taken out.

Example:

1. This is a line that wraps
2. around
3. This one isn't.
4. Here begins a new paragraph

The line break after 1. should be taken out, so the word "around" moves up. The line break after line 3 shouldn't since it's too short--so the transition to the next paragraph (line 4) is not taken out.

I hope this makes sense? (since I'm not using a programming language, I'm assuming /K won't work--at least it doesn't in the editor I'm currently using).

Thanks!

Comment: is it every 19+ chars, so after the 1st `\n`, at least 19 chars have to come again before the next `\n`? also, which language?

Comment: Which flavour of regex do you use? Why your posted sample doesn't work?

Comment: main thing wrong is you are using a negative character class, so you are matching anything that is *not* a newline.  Also, this may or may not be an issue, but some systems, Windows in particular, has `\r\n` not just `\n`.  So at a minimum, you will have this: `.{19,}\r?\n` but you need to be clear about what you actually want (show example, specify regex flavor).  Depending on those answers, you may want to use a capture group: `.{19,}(\r\n)` and look at that, or if your regex flavor supports it, `.{19,}\K(\r\n)`  but you need to be more specific about your situation and show examples.

Answer (score 0):

One very useful tool with regexp is a regexp tester, such as [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/)

That way you can see what your regex is doing. Make sure to clarify which one you are using (I program mostly in Ruby which acts a bit different then some others).

In yours, .{19,} looks for 19 or more characters, if you want EXACTLY 19, remove the comma.

```
.{19}
```

then since you don't want those 19 (or 19 plus?) characters you can use:

```
.{19}\K\n
```

\K 'forgets' what has been matched so far and moves on from that point. Very useful if your regex allows it (Ruby does not, if I recall correctly?) if you want 19 chars from the beginning of the line:

```
^.{19,}\K\n
```

and don't forget the multiline and global options if you want all matches.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO1gW0/1)

ALSO! Be sure to read Crayon Violent's comment above for more good advice (and an important Windows fact!)